# Pubnub - unsubscribe all active users from a specific channel

Tags: javascript, jquery, chat, pubnub, unsubscribe

Does anyone know if there's a Pubnub function to unsubscribe all the users from a channel at once?
And I mean without manipulating the regular function

```
pubnub.unsubscribe({
channel: 'my_channel',
callback: function() {
/* something */
}
});
```

I started building a function for mass unsubscribing myself - but hey, it's always a good idea to ask around before trying something obnoxious!

p.s - sorry if this Pubnub question has been asked before.
I looked around and it seemed unanswered.

Thanks!

Comment: How about a control channel which signals to `unsubscribe({})` from a channel on demand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## PubNub Unsubscribe All Users from a Specific Channel

Use a control channel to specify which channels all users should subscribe to.

```
// Subscribe to 'control' channel
pubnub.subscribe({
    channel : 'control',
    message : function(command) {
        // Unsubscribe Command
        if (command.type == 'unsubscribe')
            return pubnub.unsubscribe({
                channel : command.channel
            });
    }
})

// Subscribe to other channels
pubnub.subscribe({
    channel : 'ch1,ch2',
    message : function(msg) { console.log(msg) }
})
```

This will signal all users listening on the `control` channel to unsubscribe from a specific channel name.  This works pretty well out of the box.  And the signal you would send to unsubscribe will look like this:

```
pubnub.publish({
    channel : 'control',
    message : {
        command : 'unsubscribe',
        channel : 'channel_to_unsubscribe'
    }
})
```